# Blocking my vps from connecting to other vps/ip/port via sshd

Tags: block, firewall, iptables, vps, sshd

I would like to deny any connection from my vps to other `vps/ip/port via sshd`.(443)

I tried using iptables and firewall rules, seems that still nothing worked.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -j DROP ;
iptables -A FORWARD -s 1.1.1.1 -j DROP ;
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -j DROP ;
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 1.1.1.1 --dport 443 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset ;
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 1.1.1.1 --dport 443 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset ;
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 1.1.1.1 --dport 443 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset ;
iptables -I INPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT ; 
iptables -I OUTPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT ;
iptables -I FORWARD -s 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT ;
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 1 -m tcp --source 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT ;
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -m tcp --source 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT ;
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 1 -m tcp --source 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a distro that has [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) such as Ubuntu, blocking outbound connections can be easily done with the 3 commands below. What's more, this will survive reboot, unlike any `iptables` commands, which need `iptables-save` or other tool to re-apply the iptables settings after reboot.

You didn't mention other outbound connections. The commands below block all outbound connections (but not outbound *traffic* for a connection that it is initiated from the outside).

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw default allow incoming # allow inbound connections
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
```

To temporarily allow outbound connections, e.g. to download software updates:

```
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
# run your update here
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
```